# Search all vertexes for a partial property match in gremlin

Tags: graph, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have some gremlin vertexes that have the following properties (plus a few others):
label, ID, parent_id, notes, type.

I want to be able to search a value (or partial value) and return all vertexes that contain that partial property. I am also currently sorting them by label.
I am using typescript, gremlin and Neptune.

```
g.V().hasLabel('sample_label')
.or(
__.has('ID', TextP.containing(value)
__.has('parent_id', TextP.containing(value)
__.has('notes', TextP.containing(value)
__.has('type', TextP.containing(value)
)
```

However, this code either doesn't filter enough and I get data that shouldn't be there, or it doesn't return all the data I am expecting.
What is the correct gremlin query to do this?

Comment: Can you please provide a sample script that creates a graph as well as the expected output so that we know what you are looking to achieve.

Comment: the issue was i was parsing numbers as strings and js was getting mad not gremlin. thank you tho